# Add my own parameters to Facebook Login popup

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parameters, facebook-javascript-sdk

On a user's click a popup is opened :

```
FB.login(function () {
           // My CallBack
        }, { scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown' });
```

And a facebook login link is generated with a lot of parameters.

I want to add one more parameter of my own , for example `UserHasClicked=1` , but 
when I added it to the scope

```
{ scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location,UserHasClicked=1' }
```

I got `Scope Invalid` message.

How can I add my own parameter to the FB link that's generated by the `login()` mehtod ?

Comment: You mean adding a parameter to the login link of facebook ? like https://facebook.com/login/......&userHasClicked=1 ? How would you track it ? I'd advise to use tracking inside onClick functions and not external generated links

Comment: @Dinosan0908 : Exactly , I can't add my own parameter since the `login()` method generates the link and opens the popup on its own

Comment: Callback should be used to define what you want to do with the response, you should then apply the logic of click there

Comment: You can’t do that, not with FB.login, it doesn’t work that way - it does not expose the actual URL creation/opening of the popup to you. Please first of all _properly_ explain why you would need this. (And by properly, I mean better than _“some other party needs to deal with this variable”_ as you did in a comment to Dinosan0908’s answer.)

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior wanted by the login method, why not using the callback to do what you have to do with the userHasClicked logic ?

```
FB.login(function () {
           userHasClicked = true
}, { scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown' });
```

Comment: Thanks , but it doesn't work , I want to concat the `userHasClicked=1` to the url that's being opened by the `login()` method

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: Some other party needs to deal with this variable , not me.I just want to concat it to the end of the link that `login()` generates

Comment: I see, then I would advise you to read on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/ so you can tweak whatever you need to the link as you will be able to create the flow yourself . That will make it possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you want, but I assume you want to know if a user opened the login popup? Why not just do that in the callback function of your button/link/whatever:

```
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const someParm = 1;

    FB.login(() => {
        //this will get called when the user cancels or authorizes the login
        console.log(someParam); //do something with the param after auth
    }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,...'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks but It's the same thing as calling `login()` , I can't put my own params attached to this link.

Comment: i really do not see any reason why you would add your own params. what is the point? "hasClicked" sounds like you just want to know when the user opened the popup. what makes you think that you could add custom parameters to a facebook function?

Comment: in other words: what would you want to do with the custom parameter later?

Comment: Other party of the system needs to capture the link and do his own logic when he sees `hasClicked=1` , very simple.

Comment: it would always be that parameter anyway, so why even try to add it? it still does not make any sense...but i will add more info to my answer, maybe that helps. "other parties" will only get something when you hit the callback function anyway, so you can just set your custom param before calling FB.login and read it in the callback.

Comment: _“Other party of the system needs to capture the link”_ - what, the one of the login popup _itself_? Why, what is that supposed to achieve? Sounds like you are either doing things fundamentally wrong, or you are planing to do something shady.